# Keep unknown number of divs centered, max 4 per row

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a simple problem, yet I can't figure it out by myself.

In short: there are an **unknown number** of elements which I have to position in the page, max. 4 elements per row, yet still centered. This image gives you a hint (I've set it up for the sake of example):

[image: circles]

Detailed: On the image above I covered the different scenarios. So for example if there would be 5 elements total, the first and the last row should be used (4 + 1 circles). If there would be 10 items, then two times the first row and once the third (4 + 4 + 2 circles)... You get the idea. The elements (images and names are different in real-life) are retrieved from a database table in a specific order.

From a mathematical point of view, there is a pattern I think, thus it could be solved from a function in php. Since I am using Zurb Foundation 5 for the front-end, which I'm new at, one might expect that there is an easy solution using... the block grid maybe?! Here is the code for the first row (4 circles):

```
<div class="row" id="circle4">
    <div class="small-3 large-2 large-offset-2 columns text-center">
        <div class="grow pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div><h2 class="round_h2">electrocasnice</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 large-2 columns text-center">
        <div class="grow pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div><h2 class="round_h2">cosmetice</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 large-2 columns text-center">
        <div class="grow pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div><h2 class="round_h2">mobilier</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 large-2 columns text-center">
        <div class="grow pic"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div><h2 class="round_h2">parfumuri</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 large-2 columns text-center"></div>
</div>
```

The other cases (3/2/1 circles per row) are basically the same, slightly changing the offset. I've could also float the elements, giving a fixed width to the parent, but that's not possible, since it's a responsive design.

Anyway, how can I achieve this, from either `PHP` or `Foundation`?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: Here is the fiddle with the example, so you can understand better

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gC6P8/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give width & text-align to your `.row` div

```
.row{
    display:block;
    max-width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Then make your circles inline block elements

```
.small-3{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 25px 25px;
}
```

Width of .row div should be equal to resulting width of 4 cirlce. In above example it is 1000 since (200 + 25 + 25)*4 = 1000. Use your width here.

Comment: Wow! I couldn't believe what I just saw! This actually works as expected. I never thought that `inline blocks` in combination with `text-align: center` would produce the desired effect. Thank you very much. I accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the width of the divs with the circles, make them inline-blocks and center the parent div.

```
#circle4 {
    text-align: center;
}

#circle4 > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;

    /**
     * Update
     */
    float: left;
}

#circle4 > div:nth-of-type(4n) {
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. One question though. Since it's a responsive design, how would this keep max only 4 circles per row?

Comment: You could make the circle divs float and add a clear:right to every 4th div.

Comment: Huh! Good catch. Let me try this as well.

Comment: @AndrewBrown the issue with floats will be the horizontal centering, especially for the last row when there aren't 4 items.

Comment: @Jerodev I tried this, and it's not quite ok: clear right does nothing, clear left does, but not correctly.

Comment: The float not worked as needed in my case. However, I appreciate your contribution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep 4 items in one row maximum, you have to give them a % width so only 4 elements can fit horizontaly like this :

*CSS :*

```
#circle4{
    text-align: center;
}

.small-3{
    display:inline-block;
    width:23%;
}
```

You can't fit more that 4 23% width items in one row because :

```
4*23 = 92%
```

which fits in 100% and

```
5 * 23 = 115%
```

which can't fit in 100%

---

If you want to go one step further and make the content of your divs (images) responsive as well, you should add this *CSS :*

```
.grow img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/tcnnr/)**

Comment: Hi, and thanks. Actually if I'm correct, Foundation is already doing that.. Maybe I could make them simple divs (as 'not in a foundation row'), and apply those styles. I will try and come back.

Comment: I might not explained well. The width of the circles are fixed (200px), the parent container is what responsive, not the circle divs. Anyway, thank you for the demo as well.. Is very clear and useful, but not applicable in my case..

Comment: @AndrewBrown I'm sorry, I won't be able to help you unless you switch to plain CSS without foundation. I'm not familiar with it and it adds a whole lot of properties (also via media quieries) that I'm not familiar to control. you can always check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/KrA6M/14/ I made for this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853537/1811992 in plain CSS/HTML

Comment: I greatly appreciate your effort. Unfortunately I have to stick with foundation (it's for a client). The question you linked is similar to my problem, however. Let's try it clean, as you suggested. I'll setup another fiddle.

Comment: You were close to the answer. The accepted one is based on your and Jerodev's initial proposal. So thank you.