# Specific number of divs per row and keeping the rows centered as a whole on page

Tags: css

The relevant code:

```
.item-GRID {
margin: 5px;
max-width: 250px;
flex-shrink: 0;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 4px solid #f0378a;
background-color: white; }

.container-GRID {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
overflow-x: auto;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 15px; }
```

As is, the number of item-GRID divs in a row adjusts to the screen real estate so with larger resolutions, there are sometimes 5 or more items in a row. I want to make it a max of four per row without changing the size of anything.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869491/keep-unknown-number-of-divs-centered-max-4-per-row) and thus tried adding [max-width: 1080px;] to the container grid, like this:

```
.container-GRID {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
max-width: 1080px;
justify-content: center;
overflow-x: auto;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 15px; }
```

and that worked, EXCEPT, that causes the rows of divs to be aligned to the left of the page instead of staying centered on it.  With getting it to default to four per row (and automatically adapting to less per row if the window size/resolution decreases) I'm half-way there but I am now at a loss on what to change to get it to stay centered on the page.
Thank you.

P.S - if it matters, I came up with max-width of 1080 because 250 x 4 =1000 and then for math I am not sure of now, added 80 for margins.

Comment: I don't get it. In your live example it is already centering.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, I failed to say that the live example does not have the  [max-width: 1080px;]  in it. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it center by adding this css properties :

```
max-width: 1080px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Adding [margin:0 auto;] did not make a difference. I am struggling to figure out how to format a comment with links and code but http://www.colscreations.com/zOriginal.shtml is the original version and http://www.colscreations.com/zTesting.shtml is the version I added the max-width and margin auto to.

Comment: you should edit the existing margin properties. don't add a new one.
margin:0; -> margin:0 auto;

Comment: Thankyou! I missed that I had the margin property in there twice. So this issue was solved by adding [max-width: 1080px; margin: 0 auto;] to the .container-GRID. Thanks much!

Comment: I glad I can help you. Could you accept my answer then? To accept an answer, click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons.